# Rearrange the multidimensional array values using key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array, I want to rearrange array as get the parent key from each array and assign the value to that key from each array.

```
Array
    (
        [make] => Volvo 1,Volvo 2
        [model] => Make 1,Make 2
        [vehicleno] => Reg 1,reg 2
        [reg_state] => QLDS,QLDS
    )
```

Expected result as

```
Array(
[0] => Array
        (
            [make] => Volvo
            [model] => FH16
            [vehicleno] => RS95SMB
            [reg_state] => QLDS
        )
[1] => Array
        (
            [make] => Volvonew
            [model] => 123
            [vehicleno] => RS95SMB
            [reg_state] => QLDS
        )
)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: I tried using foreach but i got only the last set of results.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by extracting all the keys from original array using `array_keys()` and then using `foreach()` to grab the data for each element form the original array:

```
<?php

    $data = array(
            "make" => array("Volvo","VolvoNew"),
            "model" => array
                ( "FH16","123"
                ),
        
            "vehicleno" => array
                ("RS95SMB","RS95SMB"
                ),
        
            "reg_state" => array
                (
                    "QLDS","QLDS"
                )
        );
        
    print_r($data);
    
    $newArray = array();
    $newArrayKeys = array_keys($data);      //extract all the keys from the associative array
    $newArrayLength = count($data["make"]); //get number of makes which is the number of elements in new array
    
    for($i=0;$i<$newArrayLength;$i++){
        $currElement = array();

        // loop through all the keys from the original array and grab the data for the current index
        foreach($newArrayKeys as $key){
            $currElement[$key] = $data[$key][$i];
        }
        
        $newArray[$i] = $currElement;   //push current element to the newArray
    }
    
    print_r($newArray);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, the count of data(key) may vary.

Comment: In that case you can use isset() to check if there is any data for the current index in any of the keys from the original array and you'll be good to go. Also if the key name may vary you can get the number of elements from original array by using the first element of newArrayKeys. 
For eg: $newArrayLength = count($newArrayKeys[0]); 
or you can get the key with the maximum number of elements from the original array and then use the same number of elements for the newArray

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new array by taking the size of old variable and using for loop 
Try this

```
<?php
// pre_array is your old array and new_array is arranged one...
$i = 0;
$size = sizeof($pre_array);
$new_array = array();

for( $x=0 ; $x<$size ; $x++ ){

 $temp_array = array(
    'make'=>$pre_array['make'][$x];
    'model'=>$pre_array['model'][$x];
    'vehicleno'=>$pre_array['vehicleno'][$x];
    'reg_state'=>$pre_array['reg_state'][$x];
 );

 array_push($new_array,$temp_array);
}
print_r($new_array);
?>
```

BTW It's my first answer... hehe

Comment: It is normally recommended that you add some explanation about how it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try to do something like this

```
$array = [
    "make"      => ['Volvo', 'Volvonew'],
    "model"     => ['FH16','123'],
    "vehicleno" => ['RS95SMB','RS95SMB'],
    "reg_state" => ['QLDS', 'QLDS']
];

$list_1 = [];
$list_2 = [];

foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $list_1[$key] = $value[0];
    $list_2[$key] = $value[1];
}


var_dump($list_1);
var_dump($list_2);
```

Comment: "try this" answers are low-value on Stack Overflow because they do very little to educate/empower the OP and thousands of future researchers.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it this way with simple `foreach()` loop to iterate multidimensional array and push inner first and second element values to a new array as per your requirement.

```
$i=0;
$return = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
     $return[$i][$key] = $value[$i];
     $return[$i+1][$key] = $value[$i+1];
}
print_r(($return));
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/1CBgn

Comment: @mickmackusa added short explanation sir. Hope its ok now. Thanks for pointing me.